# Warning on == used on references (Visual Studio or ReSharper)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, resharper, equality

According to the documentation of the `==` operator in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx),

> For reference types other than string, == returns true if its two operands refer to the same object.

But, to be honest, I never check if two references are the same with `==`.
I prefer using `ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2)` and so do the default override of the `Equals` function.

Therefore, in my projects, when the == operator is used on other types than string, equals to a bug.

Is there a way to trigger a warning/error through Visual Studio or ReSharper when == is used on references (apart from string)?

Comment: You could [create your own analyzer](https://www.meziantou.net/writing-a-roslyn-analyzer.htm)

Comment: Thanks @Crowcoder, this seems a possible solution. But it surprises me that there isn't already something to solve this.

Comment: Analyzers are what solves this. They are used by visual studio and resharper to provide that functionality.

Comment: but what if the object is overriding the equals method?

Comment: Then the analyzer can detect that too?

Comment: @itsme86 it must. With Roslyn it should be pretty easy to do, but still, long. I'm still hoping that some ReSharper genie knows about 'that' option to do it hassle-free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, I created an extension to do that.

[image]

If you're interested, here is the link to the [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Oswego.0001) in the marketplace.
And here is the link to the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/AlvinSartor/equalschecker-vs-extension).

At the moment it does **not** check if the object has an override for the operators "==" and "!=". Whoever wants to contribute is more than welcome to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a global solution, but if we want to consider only some classes, the `CannotApplyEqualityOperatorAttribute` in `JetBrains.Annotations` does the trick.

```
[CannotApplyEqualityOperator]
public sealed class NonEquatable { }

public sealed class OtherClass
{
    public bool DoForbiddenStuff()
    {
        var obj1 = new NonEquatable();
        var obj2 = new NonEquatable();

        // ERROR! 'Cannot apply equality operator to type marked by CannotApplyEqualityOperatorAttribute'
        return obj1 == obj2; 
    }
}
```

Still waiting to see if there is a more generalized alternative.