# How to negate ExpressionSyntax using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions

I am making a VS extension related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59460431/warning-on-used-on-references-visual-studio-or-resharper) question.

Having an `ExpressionSyntax` containing `Equals(o1, o2)`, sometimes I would like to negate it to `!Equals(o1, o2)`.
I haven't really found a way to negate an expression, so I am improvising.

Until now I tried:

```
        private static InvocationExpressionSyntax Negate(ExpressionSyntax invocation)
        {
            var syntaxList = new SeparatedSyntaxList<SyntaxNode>();
            var argumentList = SyntaxFactory.ArgumentList(syntaxList).AddArguments(SyntaxFactory.Argument(invocation));
            var negation = SyntaxFactory.InvocationExpression(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("!"), argumentList);
            return SyntaxFactory.InvocationExpression(negation);
        }
```

But it gives the error: "Info = error CS0103: The name '!' does not exist in the current context".

Any idea how this (in theory simple operation) can be performed?

Comment: What about using `SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.ExclamationToken)`

Comment: @Eldar I also thought about that, but then I didn't find a way to "attach" it to the ExpressionSyntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `PrefixUnaryExpression(SyntaxKind.LogicalNotExpression, ...)` for this purpose.

e.g. from [ContractCSharpSyntaxRewriter.cs#L272](https://github.com/deniszykov/code-contracts-remover/blob/2345ef9899ea8070278aa3485b9d918af4d326fd/CodeContractsRemover/ContractCSharpSyntaxRewriter.cs#L272):

```
using static Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory;

private ExpressionSyntax InverseExpressionWithNot(ExpressionSyntax checkExpression)
{
    if (checkExpression == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(checkExpression));
    }

    return PrefixUnaryExpression(SyntaxKind.LogicalNotExpression, ParenthesizedExpression(checkExpression));
}
```

See also MSDN [`SyntaxFactory.PrefixUnaryExpression(SyntaxKind, ExpressionSyntax)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntaxfactory.prefixunaryexpression?view=roslyn-dotnet)

If for another expression you need to identify the Roslyn calls required, I recommend the tool [Roslyn Quoter](https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/), which will provide the calls for an arbitrary expression:

[image: Screenshot of RoslynQuoter]